# Distribution of dark matter

Tags: dark-matter

Searching to understand how dark matter is distributed, I find many references like this:
https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-57244708

Basically they state that dark matter exists wherever we look and it is not concentrated in any region of the sky.

But I cannot find any data that describe the distribution as a function of distance. In other words, are the effects of dark matter more pronounced for further away stellar objects?

Comment: Possibly useful: [New dark matter map reveals cosmic mystery](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-57244708), [The distribution of dark matter in galaxies](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08843), [Dark Matter Distribution](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/dark-matter-distribution), [Dark Energy, Dark Matter](https://science.nasa.gov/astrophysics/focus-areas/what-is-dark-energy), and [Dark Energy Survey releases most precise look at the universe’s evolution](https://news.fnal.gov/2021/05/dark-energy-survey-releases-most-precise-look-at-the-universes-evolution/).